# XMLUnit Compare Xml Ignoring Sequence

Tags: xml, comparison, xmlunit

I need to compare 2 XML's for which I am using my custom Difference Listener which is ignoring Child Node Sequence and Attribute List Sequence:

```
if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE_ID ||
    difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.ATTR_SEQUENCE_ID) 
return DifferenceListener.RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
```

My code works well for :

```
    <xml>
        <elem1 att1="abc" att2="def"></elem1>
        <elem1></elem1>
    </xml>
```

and

```
    <xml>
        <elem1></elem1>
        <elem1 att2="def" att1="abc"></elem1>
    </xml>
```

However I need it to consider these XML's as identical as well:

```
<xml>
    <elem1>
      <elem2>
         <id>ABC</id>
         .....
      </elem2>
    </elem1>
    <elem1>
      <elem2>
         <id>DEF</id>
         .....
      </elem2>
    </elem1>
</xml>
```

and

```
<xml>
    <elem1>
      <elem2>
         <id>DEF</id>
         .....
      </elem2>
    </elem1>
    <elem1>
      <elem2>
         <id>ABC</id>
         .....
      </elem2>
    </elem1>
</xml>
```

Here I want comparison to consider both elem1's in both XML are identical as only sequence is mixed up. So I need my code to work for more than one nesting level. Is that possible with XMLUnit?
Please help anyone ?

I found a temporary Solution (Cant add Comment on my own ques for 8 hrs):

I was earlier overriding the ElementQualifier with: ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier, If I change that to RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier, I can get my desired result

```
xmlDiff.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier());
```

You can also use multiLevelElementNameandTextQualifier for deepr level XML compare. Recursive is for level 1 only.

For further Details your can refer: http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/ar01s03.html#ElementQualifier Example 20

I need to match Element Name and Attributes and this matches Name and Text .. but still .. for now its working so I am using it ..

Will update if I find better solution

Hope this is helpful for someone :)

Comment: RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier isn't working for me.

I need something like: RecursiveElementNameAndAttributeQualifier which doesnt Exist in XMLUnit1.4

Something that will:
1. Match NodeName+AttributeList to locate comparable nodes
2. Match NodeValues and then decide if acceptable

A mix of ElementNameAndAttributeQulalfier and RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier.

Any Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Hello, did you find something that responds your answer? I'm having the same trouble as you... EDIT!!! Just found it... ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier did the trick to me =)

Answer (score 0):

`ElementQualifier` is what tells XMLUnit which elements to compare.  If the built-in `ElementQualifier`s don't work for you, you can provide an implementation of the interface yourself.